# Launch Brightcove video player fullscreen from anchor link on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, brightcove

I would like to launch a full screen video launch from anchor link on a mobile page.

```
<a href="javascript:void();" click="openVideo();">PLAY</a>
```

We are looking for an experience similar to the iOS HTML5 video experience across devices with an icon replacing the thumbnail.

The video is housed on Brightcove. I do not need to use the Brightcove SmartPlayer HTML5, but would like to in the hope that it would downgrade better.

I have been able to get a buggy version of this to work on most iOS devices by resizing the video element and hiding it under a play icon and launching the video with JavaScript, but Andriod devices want to play the video under the icon which makes sense. I would rather not kludge this solution.

CSS:

```
<style>
#play {
    display:block;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:75px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
#video {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<video width="100" height="100" tabindex="0" controls="controls" preload="auto" id="video">
    <source type="video/mp4;" src="video.mp4"></source>
</video>
<a href="#" id="play">&#187;</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var children = video.children;
for (var i=0,j=children.length; i<j; i++) {
  if (children[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "SOURCE") {
    var canPlay = video.canPlayType(children[i].type);
    if(canPlay == "probably" || canPlay == "maybe") {
      video.src = children[i].src;
      video.load();
      break; // or return or whatever
    }
  }
}

video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},true);

var aVideo = document.getElementById('play');
aVideo.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},false);
</script>
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to automate the full screen activation when viewing a video on a device.

Comment: Hi Christian, I got a long way with videojs.com. but was still having issues with full screen on all browsers on Android. With brightcove you have to use their js api to get the ever changing url for the video. What I ended up doing was launching a new page with the video on it and then using a video ended callback to go back in history. Completely kludgey, but it did get the job done for now. Still looking for a good solution so let me know what you find. james